# Submit page item values to session in the on-Demand ajax process (PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle-apex

Every time an ajax call is made. I need to get the current values of items to the session state.

I know I can do this from JS in the apex.server.process call by setting appropriate "pageItems" Parameter.

But is there a way to set the items current value to session in the plsql block of the ajax process instead of doing it on the client-side using pageItems parameter in apex.server process

In short : I need to know,in the server, the current client-side value of items in the page every time a call is sent to the server using ajax. And this should be done without any client-side code involved.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit items to the session"?

Comment: Set the current value of items to session.If user changes the value of a page item we know it will not be reflected in the session unless we submit the items by using pageItems param in JS apex.server.process call. Is there a similar way of doing it in plsql of ajax process instead of using pageItems param

Comment: No, it's at that moment the PL/SQL is invoked, that the information from the browser must be submitted and sent to the server call. I've been using the declarative PL/SQL Dynamic Action more often now.